# How to get the value of xml node if namespace is prefix on it

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

I want to get the value of XML node using Xpath and XSLT. Below is the input XML and and my XSLT code.

Below is the request xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:nat="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xyz.DigitalBanking.Service.Token" xmlns:urn="urn:xyz:ASML:2.0:assertion">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <nat:GetAdfsSAMLFromASML>

             <nat:request>

            <nat:applicationType>secure_inbox</nat:applicationType>
                <nat:department>Internet_Bank</nat:department>
                <nat:firstName>quae divum incedo</nat:firstName>
                <nat:lastName>verrantque per auras</nat:lastName>
                <nat:title>per auras</nat:title>
                <nat:emailaddress>sdd55@BBM.TUX</nat:emailaddress>
                <nat:mejrgeOnAttribute>sdd55@BBM.TUX</nat:mejrgeOnAttribute>
                <nat:ExistingASMLToken>

    </nat:ExistingASMLToken>
             </nat:request>
          </nat:GetAdfsSAMLFromASML>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is the xsl code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
        xmlns:pbdp="http://datapower.common.stp.pbds.pbit.jpmc.com" 
        xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config"
        xmlns:nw="http://www.datapower.com/extensions/functions"
        xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
        xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
        xmlns:nat="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xyz.DigitalBanking.Service.Token"      

        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        >

        -->



        <xsl:template match="/">

            <xsl:variable name="c">'</xsl:variable>


            <xsl:variable name="applicationType" select="string(//*[local-name()='nat:GetAdfsSAMLFromASML']/@*[local-name()='nat:request']/@*[local-name()

    ='nat:applicationType'])"/>
                    <xsl:value-of-select= "$applicationType"/>


        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to fetch the value of `<nat:applicationType>` . i.e. output should come **secure_inbox**.

I tried with above xslt but didn't get the desired output.

Comment: Please don't change your question after it has been answered - post a new one, if necessary.

Comment: What is going on here? Why do you keep editing the question? Are you trying to ask a new question?

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:nat="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xyz.DigitalBanking.Service.Token" 
exclude-result-prefixes="soapenv nat">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/nat:GetAdfsSAMLFromASML/nat:request/nat:applicationType"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>secure_inbox</result>
```